# Why does craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath return an empty string?

Tags: pagination, request

I'm trying to use [`craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getQueryStringWithoutPath) to handle query strings on pagination, but for some reason it always seems to return an empty string. If I try `craft.request.getQueryString()` I get the query string as expected (eg. `foo=bar`), but with the exact same URL `getQueryStringWithoutPath()` gives me an empty string.

Am I doing something wrong? Could this be a server configuration issue (I'm using Apache 2.4 with a fairly default configuration)? Or could this be a Craft bug...? I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: Per Brad's answer, this is a bug and has been fixed for the next release. Closing as a "bug report".

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a bug that only occurred if the existing URL didn't have an URI associated with it.  i.e. `http://craft.dev?foo=bar`.

It's been fixed and will be included in the next 2.5 beta release (or the first 2.5 public release if you don't want to swap to the beta track).

Comment: Ah, spot on, thanks Brad - the issue was on the home page so sounds like that's it. Out of interest, is there a schedule (even a rough one) for the 2.5 public release yet? No problem if not, but thought I'd check.

Comment: Yup... read in here: http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/craft-2.5-beta

Comment: Yikes, sorry, missed that! Next week - that's excellent. Thanks again.